# Why given code is generating 'The request limit for the database is X' with Azure SQL

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, dapper

So I have code running in Azure Functons Consumption Plan. My database is limited to 60 concurrent logins or something that is generating this error:

```
The request limit for the database is X
```

My questions is, why this loop within transaction is geting this limit? One transactions is one request? Or not? I know that code is in poor quality, but this is only because I was playing with hardcore solutions during my search.

```
SOME_QUERY1 = "INSERT INTO SomeTable (p1,p2,p3,p4) Values (p1,p2,p3,p4); SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)";
SOME_QUERY2 = "INSERT INTO OtherTable (10 fields)"; 

public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> SaveBusinessTransaction(TransactionBatchEntity businessEntity)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var successfullyAddedTransactions = new List<string>();

        using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                var transactionId = (await connection.QueryAsync<int>(SOME_QUERY1, new { Paramter = 1 }, transaction)).Single();

                foreach (var details in businessEntity.Details)
                {
                    var detailsEntity = new
                    {
                        //some fields
                    };

                    await connection.ExecuteAsync(SOME_QUERY2, detailsEntity, transaction);
                    successfullyAddedTransactions.Add(detailsEntity.TransactionNumber);
                }

                transaction.Commit();

                return successfullyAddedTransactions;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                connection.Close();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

IMPORTANT missing part with an execution context

```
transactions.ForEach(t => _sqlService.SaveBusinessTransaction(t));
```

Comment: Does sp_who show anything useful?

Comment: What makes you think it is due to the loop? Could it be because the function is being run more than 60 times 'at a time' (i.e. by different callers)?

Comment: @mjwills it is not running more than once at time and ' catch (Exception)' is catching this exception while only this is loop running.

Comment: @Alex K. sp_who is not showing usefull things. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging I found out the reason, sadly one level above.

```
transactions.ForEach(t => _sqlService.SaveBusinessTransaction(t));
```

As we can see this is Fire Forget, a temporary solution was obvious

```
transactions.ForEach(t => await _sqlService.SaveBusinessTransaction(t));
```

Long term solution is to change DB schema, but this is not the topic for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ed3f139d-7a99-45d0-bab0-1f67ba6e058a/our-db-went-down-with-quotthe-request-limit-for-the-database-is-90-and-has-been-reachedquot?forum=ssdsgetstarted), it can help you. It's recent and it's a Bug from their side.

> *"Looks like there was an issue on the back end regarding the HADR TRANSPORT service not being up for about two hours.
> Apparently, the SQL service was restarted and the HADR TRANSPORT service did not start as expected."*

Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37919964/8215147).

> *"Sql server sometime uses more than one worker thread to execute a query so the number of connections doesn't always correspond to the number of execution threads."*
>
> *"Since Azure SQL doesn't support setting this parameter globally, our solution was to add OPTION (MAXDOP 1) to the offending query so its execution would be more predictable (at the cost of parallelism and speed)."*

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20584771)

Comment: Updated @Daz. Thank you for your feedback!